# Replace Quotes by ASCII chars

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have table that stores for a set of attributes from a given table the attribute name and the targetvalue to update it to.

For Example:

```
AttributeName   | TargetValue
CustomerName    | Tom
CustomerAddress | The ' road
...
```

As you can see it is possible that there is a single quote in a target value.

I want to have dynamic sql that creates the following output:

```
UPDATE T1
SET CustomerName = 'Tom',
CustomerAddress = 'The ' + CHAR(39) + ' road'
...
FROM Target T1
INNER JOIN MyList T2
ON...
```

So in simple words:
Create from the variable below

```
DECLARE @Word NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'I '' have '' quotes'
SELECT @Word
```

the following output:

```
'I ' + CHAR(39) + ' have ' + CHAR(39) + ' quotes'
```

Comment: Why not use : CustomerAddress LIKE '%The road%'

Comment: What are you trying to solve here. The approach you described doesn't seem much real world rationality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

select '''' + replace(@Word, '''', ''' + CHAR(39) + ''') + ''''

That will get you the result you wanted.

Comment: Great! I also went that way, however I totally got messed up with the number of quotes. This does the trick! thank you